# Corrective Suggestions for Modal closure on form submit

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

Corrective Suggestions for Modal closure on form submit

I am aware that this question may have been asked by another person previously but pardon me, i just need corrections for my code here that deals with form submission in the background with AJAX. Am new to AJAX and i find it rather challenging. Your help and input is greatly appreciated

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<body>
<form method="post" id="login">
                <div class="w3-user">
                    <span><i class="fa fa-user-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="email" required="">
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <div class="w3-psw">
                    <span><i class="fa fa-key" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required="">
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <div class="w3l-check">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
                    <span><a href="#">forgot password ?</a></span>  
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <div class="signin">
                    <input type="submit" value="sign in">
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            
            </form>
<-- //Ajax code to handle the form to prevent the modal from closing on submission -->
<script>
$("#login").on("submit",function(e)){
        var formData=$(this).serialize();
        e.preventDefault():
        $.ajax({
            url: 'log.php',
            data: formData,
            type:'post',
            success:function(data){
                $('#login').replaceWith(data);
            }
        });
    };
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what you mean by this `$('#login').replaceWith(data);`????

Comment: I would highly recommend you using general Jquery approach for ajax operations. Then you don't need all the hassle.

Comment: $('#IDModal').modal('hide');

Comment: I dont even know, i just copied some code from another user's question and pasted it into the sign in form

Comment: You send Ajax with Jquery then you simlpy set $('#somediv').html("Hello motto") and window is not closing.

The key here is to process button click with Jquery insted of action in forms.

Comment: so what you want???

Comment: I think that is the part where the response from the server is passed onto the form like errors and stuff

Comment: Here is the explanation, just read it and you will be fine

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp

Comment: @Undry thats a little bit complex, i just wanna slay this with Ajax

Comment: your login is done properly ???

Comment: what you actually want to achieve???

Comment: @CoderTimothy actually it is not. Using this is much more elegant and structured. Try to read on jquery and ajax as soon as you understand that you will find it very simple and flexible. Good luck

Comment: @KUMAR its a login form and i want user input processed with ajax

Answer (score 0):

**HTML FORM For Login :-**

```
<form method="post" id="login">
    <div class="w3-user">
        <span><i class="fa fa-user-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="email" required="">
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="w3-psw">
        <span><i class="fa fa-key" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" required="">
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="w3l-check">
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
        <span><a href="#">forgot password ?</a></span>  
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="signin">
        <input type="submit" value="sign in">
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</form>
```

**AJAX JQUERY CODE:-**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#login').submit(function() {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'data_check.php',
            data: {
                email: $("#email").val(),
                password: $("#password").val()
            },
            success: function(data)
            {
                if (data === 'Correct') {
                    window.location.replace('dashboard.php');
                }
                else {
                    alert(data);
                }
            }
        });
        //this is mandatory other wise your from will be submitted.
        return false; 
    });

});
</script>
```

**data_check.php**

```
<?php

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :email AND password = :password");
$stmt->execute(array(
    ':email' => $email,
    ':password' => $pass
));

$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$affected_rows = $stmt->rowCount();

if ($affected_rows == 1) {
    //add the user to our session variables
    $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
    echo 'Correct';
} else {
    echo 'Incorrect username/password';
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks @Kumar bro I really appreciate it

Comment: Do I need to add jquery import for ajax to work or Ajax is inbuilt into the browser?

Comment: @Coder Timothy you need to import it .

Comment: Yeah it did Thanks @Kumar